# Regex negated character disjunction

Tags: regex

Very quick and simple question.

Consider the vector of character strings ("AvAv", "AvAvAv")

Why does the pattern (Av)\1([^A]|$) match *both* strings?

The pattern says have an isntance of "Av", have another, then ***either*** have a character that is not an "A" ***or else*** come to an end. The first string clearly matches, the latter I do not see how it does. It has two copies of "Av" but then it fails to end (missing the second disjunct), and fails to be followed by a charavter other than "A" (missing the first disjunct), so how does the pattern successfully match it?

Thank you so much for your time and assistance. It is greatly appreciated.

Comment: because the regex not use `^`, so it can match start from the second `Av`

Comment: I think the regex only needs to match a part of the string to be considered "a match".

Comment: The answer is, as usual, [here](https://regex101.com/r/bLOF88/1), *EXPLANATION* pane is on the right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an explanation:

```
AvAv    - matches (Av)\1$
```

In this case, we can match `Av`, followed by that captured quantity, followed by `$` from the alternation.  In the case of `AvAvAv` we also have a match:

```
AvAvAv  - again matches (Av)\1$
  ^^^^  last four letters match
```

It is the same logic here, except that in order to match, we have to skip the first `Av`.

If the pattern were `^(Av)\1([^A]|$)` then only `AvAv` would be a match.

Answer (score 0):

A RegEx only needs to match a part of the string to be considered "a match".

In other words, your RegEx matches this part:

> Av**AvAv**

for the second example.

If you don't want it to match the second one, use a caret `^`

```
^(Av)\1([^A]|$)
```

In this way the second one won't be matched.